# What does "as...as" mean in this sentence?

Tags: comparative-constructions

This sentence is taken from Chapter 1 of Barack Obama's new book ***'A promised land'***:

> *"It seemed like it sprang out of nowhere, as grassroots a political campaign as anything mordern politics had ever seen."*

Can anyone explain why there are 2 nouns following the first 'as'? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grassroots is being used as an adjective here to describe "political campaign" and it means something like "authentic" or "populist."

It is a typical "as... as" usage to compare two things, but one is specified and one isn't. In that way it functions to say that the thing being compared is superlatively [adjective].

> The campaign was as grassroots as anything. → The campaign was more grassroots than the others.

Consider a similar "as... as" structure:

> He had never seen *as blue a sky as* he did after the storm.

> She had never smelled *as delicious a cake as* the one baking in the oven.

Comment: Thank you. It's been a couple of months since I asked the question. I never thought grassroots could be used as an adjective. Now it makes a lot of sense.